# Sending e-mail to multiple recipients

Tags: c#, email

I want to send e-mail to multiple recipients in C# through Gmail. This is my code, but this code only send email to one address. How should I modify it?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (textBox1.Text == "" || richTextBox1.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill out the boxes!");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

            message.From = new MailAddress("tamogatas.dolgozoadatbazis@gmail.com");
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(Form1.cimzett));
            message.Subject = textBox1.Text;
            message.Body = richTextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine +  "This message was sent from " + (Login.loginnev);

            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USERNAME@gmail.com", "PASSWORD");
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Send(message);
            MessageBox.Show("The mail was sent successfully!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.Message);
        }
}
```

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Did you copy-paste it from somewhere? It is extremely clear in your code how you send it to multiple recipients at once. BTW, thanks for your password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (textBox1.Text == "" || richTextBox1.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill out the boxes!");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

            message.From = new MailAddress("tamogatas.dolgozoadatbazis@gmail.com");
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(Form1.cimzett)); <---- THIS LINE
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("lalala@gmail.com"));
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("lalala3@gmail.com"));
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("lalala2@gmail.com"));
            message.Subject = textBox1.Text;
            message.Body = richTextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine +  "This message was sent from " + (Login.loginnev);

            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USERNAME@gmail.com", "PASSWORD");
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Send(message);
            MessageBox.Show("The mail was sent successfully!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.Message);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] emails={"n1@gmail.com","n2@gmail.com","n3@gmail.com","n4@gmail.com"};
foreach(var items as emails)
{

  MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

            message.From = new MailAddress(items);
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(Form1.cimzett));
            message.Subject = textBox1.Text;
            message.Body = richTextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine +  "This message was sent from " + (Login.loginnev);

            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("tamogatas.dolgozoadatbazis@gmail.com", "adminisztrator0");
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Send(message);
            MessageBox.Show("The mail was sent successfully!");
}
```

Comment: This creates multiple emails which is completely wrong

Comment: Hi DasturchiUZ, your answer looks to account for multiple emails 'incoming' and processing those; but I think, the questioner wants to send multiple emails 'post' processing - for whatever reason. The question is vaguely worded, no fault of yours. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code, however to address the primary issue it looks like you are relying on `richTextBox1.Text` to supply the email, however this is an assumption

So where you are doing:
`message.To.Add(new MailAddress(Form1.cimzett));`, maybe change `Form1.cimzett` to `richTextBox1.Text`?

In addition you can declare all of the `SmtpClient`code outside of the Button logic, and instead declare it in this class.